# Freely available translations of the Dhammapada

Tags: dhammapada

I'm looking for translations of the Dhammapada that are freely available to quote in part or in full. I would like a variety of alternative translation so can anyone give a comprehensive list - online and/or printed publications.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a list:

- [AccessToInsight's Dhammapada](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/index.html) - various translations (Buddharakkhita, Thanissaro, and a few others) - web-based
- [Suttacentral's Dhammapada](https://suttacentral.net/dhp) - various translations (Anandajoti, Buddharakkhita) - web-based
- [Ven. Thanissaro's translation of Dhammapada](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/damapada.pdf) - in PDF
- [Ven. Thanissaro's translation of Dhammapada](http://www.buddhismtoday.com/english/texts/khuddaka/dhp/index.html) - web-based
- [Acharya Buddharakkhita's translation of Dhammapada](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/scrndhamma.pdf) - in PDF
- [Ven. Anandajoti's translation of Dhammapada](https://www.holybooks.com/wp-content/uploads/Dhamma-Verses.pdf) - in PDF, includes Pali text
- [Ven. Anandajoti's translation of Dhammapada](https://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/Texts-and-Translations/Dhammapada/index.htm) - web-based, PDF, epub and MOBI, includes Pali text
- [Ven. Narada's translation of Dhammapada](https://www.readingfaithfully.org/dhammapada-translated-by-ven-narada-pdf/) - in PDF, epub and MOBI
- [Bhikkhu Pesala's version of Ven. Narada's Dhammapada](http://www.aimwell.org/dhammapada.html) - web-based, enhanced with commentary
- [Ven. Weragoda Sarada Thero's translation of Dhammapada](https://www.buddhistelibrary.org/buddhism-online/e-books/dhammapada-txt.pdf) - in PDF, includes commentary and Pali text
- [Ven. Weragoda Sarada Thero's translation of Dhammapada](http://www.buddhanet.net/dhammapada/) - web-based, illustrated
- [P. Lal's translation of Dhammapada](http://read.goodweb.net.cn/PDF/p34/The%20Dhammapada.pdf) - in PDF
- [Buddhist Legends, translated by E. W. Burlingame](http://www.readingfaithfully.org/buddhist-legends-dhammapada-origin-stories-burlingame-kindle-ebook/) - in epub, MOBI - complete stories of the Dhammapada
- [Thomas Byrom's translation of Dhammapada](http://www.insightflorida.org/uploads/dhammapada.pdf) - in PDF, rendered into English poetry
- [Max Müller's translation of the Dhammapada](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2017) - web-based, MOBI and epub

You can find many more Dhammapada PDF versions [here](https://static.sirimangalo.org/pdf/).

Comment: Wow those are great.

Answer (score 6):

https://nanda.online-dhamma.net/tipitaka/sutta/khuddaka/dhammapada/dhp-contrast-reading/dhp-contrast-reading-en/

Eight translations side by side

- Pāḷi Tipiṭaka (PTS) [1]
- Pāḷi Tipiṭaka (CSCD) [2]
- Translated from the Pali by Ven Nārada Thera ) [3]
- Translated from the Pali by Ven. Ācharya Buddharakkhita ) [4]
- Translated from the Pali by Ven. Thanissaro Bhikkhu ) [5]
- Translated from the Pali by Ven. Varado Bhikkhu ) [6]
- Translated from the Pali by Friedrich Max Müller) [7]
- Cited from DLMBS [8]

Answer (score 4):

The Dhammapada: Verses and Stories

Dhammapada is one of the best known books of the Pitaka. It is a collection of the teachings of the Buddha expressed in clear, pithy verses. These verses were culled from various discourses given by the Buddha in the course of forty-five years of his teaching, as he travelled in the valley of the Ganges (Ganga) and the sub-mountain tract of the Himalayas. These verses are often terse, witty and convincing. Whenever similes are used, they are those that are easily understood even by a child, e.g., the cart's wheel, a man's shadow, a deep pool, flowers. Through these verses, the Buddha exhorts one to achieve that greatest of all conquests, the conquest of self; to escape from the evils of passion, hatred and ignorance; and to strive hard to attain freedom from craving and freedom from the round of rebirths. Each verse contains a truth (dhamma), an exhortation, a piece of advice.

https://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/

Comment: This answer is not useful. OP asks for "a comprehensive list".

Comment: Just Google it. I gave my best option here.

Comment: I thinks this answer is useful -- I don't think this one was mentioned in other answers, and this one is for various reasons one of my favourite editions.