# Looking for Dhammapada in Ebook format

Tags: books, dhammapada

I'm looking for a collection of the entire Dhammapada in Ebook format (not PDF-format) that can be read in the Kindle App. Free or paid.

I've been looking myself without finding anything. Maybe someone else has better luck than me. The book has to contain all Dhammapada verses.

Thanks.

Comment: [Try these ones, mate!](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=dhammapada+kindle&crid=32VYOXOMFWV2&sprefix=dhammapada+kindle%2Caps%2C68&ref=nb_sb_noss)

Comment: Related: [Freely available translations of the Dhammapada](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/39519/471)

Comment: Thank you guys:)

Answer (score 2):

Here are three different free ebook with quality translations. Two are offered with English-Pali in addition to just English.

- [Dhammapada: The Buddha’s Path of Wisdom, Translated by Acharya Buddharakkhita, Kindle, Epub, PDF, MP3](https://readingfaithfully.org/canonical-collections-for-practice/dhammapada-translated-by-acharya-buddharakkhita-kindle-epub-pdf-mp3/)
- [Dhammapada: Translated by Ven. Narada, PDF, Kindle, Epub](http://readingfaithfully.org/canonical-collections-for-practice/dhammapada-translated-by-ven-narada-pdf/)
- [Ebook Translations by Bhikkhu Sujato in Epub, Kindle, PDF](https://readingfaithfully.org/ebook-translations-by-bhikkhu-sujato-in-epub-kindle-pdf/)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three more:

- [Anandajoti Bhikkhu's translation of Dhammapada](https://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/Texts-and-Translations/Dhammapada/index.htm) - epub, MOBI and PDF, includes Pali text
- [Buddhist Legends, translated by E. W. Burlingame](http://www.readingfaithfully.org/buddhist-legends-dhammapada-origin-stories-burlingame-kindle-ebook/) - in epub, MOBI - complete stories of the Dhammapada
- [Dhammapada translated by Max Müller](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2017), MOBI and epub

Comment: Thank you so much.